# Ubuntu Server on VMware Workstation + VMware Tools installed, any way to enable copy-paste support between guest and host?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 on a virtual machine on VMware Workstation and VMware Tools are properly installed, however there doesn't seem to be any support for copy-pasting between the host and the guest. I understand I can ssh to it, but for the times when I need to explicitly work on the virtual machine with no external sessions, it's a pain. Is there any workaround besides using SSH?

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipboard-sync/dapdfappilfdiljfpjcbkmkblldaemjg?hl=en

This extension would work if you have a GUI on your vmware install.

EDIT: And use chrome.